# Cannot change model instance after a ValidationError is thrown in django admin area

Tags: python, django

Imagine a model like this:

```
class CFile(models.Model):
   filepath   = models.FileField(upload_to=...)
   collection = models.ForeignKey("FileCollection",null=True)
   ... # other attributes that are not relevant

   def clean(self):
     bname = os.path.basename
     if self.collection:
       cfiles = self.baseline.attachment_set.all()
       with_same_basename = filter(lambda e: bname(e.filepath.path) == bname(self.filepath.path),cfiles)
       if len(with_same_basename) > 0:
         raise ValidationError("There already exists a file with the same name in this collection")   

class FileCollection(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  files= models.ManyToManyField("CFile")
```

I want to disallow the upload of a CFile if there already exists a CFile with the same basename, that's why I added the `clean`. The problem is:

- I upload a CFile, with the name `file1.png` -> gets uploaded because no other files with this name exist
- I upload another CFile, with the name `file1.png` -> I get the expected error that I already have a file with this name. So, I try to change the file, and upload a file with a different name ( `file2.png` ). The problem is, I stopped via pdb in the clean, and the model instance is still `file1.png`. I imagine this happens because of my ValidationError and django allows me to "correct my mistake". The problem is I cannot correct it if I cannot upload another file. How can I handle this?

EDIT: This happens in the admin area, sorry for forgetting to mention this before. I don't have anything custom ( besides `inlines = [ FileInline ]` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the clearest way is to declare another field in your model for filename and make it unique for every collection. Like this:

```
class CFile(models.Model):
   filepath   = models.FileField(upload_to=...)
   collection = models.ForeignKey("FileCollection",null=True, related_name='files')
   filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   ... # other attributes that are not relevant

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('filename', 'collection'),)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.filename = bname(self.filepath.path)
        super(CFile, self).save(args, kwargs)
```

Comment: I am using a `RandomFileStorage`, because there may be more than one `FileCollection`s having a `CFile` with this name. So, I don't think it will find it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Tempus Never heard about `RandomFileStorage` (and google gave me 0 results). But I'm pretty sure Django will rename file automatically if there is a file with this name.

Comment: Sorry, the power went off as I was writing about RandomFileStorage. It's just a storage that ensures that a file is uploaded to a folder whose name is generated randomly. It's important that a file keeps the same name ( automatic renames are not okay ).

Comment: @Tempus If it is important may be it's better to add another field in model – `filename` with `unique=True` (and populate it in `save` method). I think it will be clearer.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't this require it to be unique among all CFiles? If I have two FileCollections, I want each to have the possibility of having a file named ( for example ) `a.txt`. Can the uniqueness be specified to apply only inside the FileCollection ?

Comment: @Tempus Yes, my mistake, you should use [`Meta.unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) `(('filename', collection),)`

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look, could you update your answer in the meanwhile?

Comment: I get an IntegrityError now, saying `columns filename, collection_id are not unique`

Comment: @Tempus Have you reflected your changes in DB somehow (DROP then syncdb, or with south, or manually)?

Comment: I am using an sqlite db for my developing, I deleted the file and resynced.

Comment: I think the problem is because of this: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/702 , and this just brings me back to my code :D

Comment: @Tempus Hm, you don't need `files` field in your `FileCollection` model. Use `related_name` for that (see my answer). Then you can use `some_collection.files` with same effect.

Comment: I get a message saying that the filename already exists in this collection, but if I upload something else, django thinks I'm still trying to upload the image on which validation failed.

Comment: @Tempus I think it's a problem of your view, can you show it?

Comment: This happens in the admin area. I don't have anything custom in there.