# How can I use the same storage on a form that's not backed up by a model in django?

Tags: django

Let's say I have this form:

```
class SimpleUploadForm(forms.Form):
   file = forms.FileField()
```

I have this model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   first_file = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/%Y/%m/%d",storage=MyCustomStorage())
   second_file = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/%Y/%m/%d",storage=MyCustomStorage())
```

for which I also provide a ModelForm. The view part for the `SimpleUploadForm` is like this:

```
def simple_upload(request):
   ...
   if request.method == "POST":
      form = SimpleUploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
         # what do I need to do here to save the file in the same place where the `MyModel` ModelForm is saving them?
      else:
        ...
```

I don't know how to use the `storage` and `upload_to` fields without a ModelForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your storage like any other class. Its API is [well-documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/storage/).

Or you can set [DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#default-file-storage) in `settings.py`, and it will be used automatically for all your file operations.

Comment: How do I replicate the `upload_to="uploads/%Y/%m/%d"`?

Comment: @Tempus You storage should handle this is `save` method. Or, if you inherit from `FileSystemStorage` you can pass `location` arg to its constructor. And `ModelForm` is not an option?

Comment: I don't really need to store anything to database in this case. I'm just processing a report and displaying the processing result. Is there a possibility to use a ModelForm without a table?

Comment: @Tempus Why do you need some custom storage here? You will get the file object, process it as you like. Saving it in `uploads/%Y/%m/%d` is one line of code.

Comment: Because there may exist a file with that same name :)

Comment: @Tempus Is it the [same project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293333/cannot-change-model-instance-after-a-validationerror-is-thrown-in-django-admin-a)? I think you overcomplicate things. If you want original filename, hold it as a string and let Django do all the file operations.

Comment: Yes, it's the same project :)